# srmklive/paypal payment authorization without immediate capture

Tags: laravel, paypal

I am trying to setup paypal payment authorization in my laravel app so the seller has the option to review the offer and reject payment if he wants on his paypal business dashboard rather than receive the complete payment right away and unnecessarily be charged for transaction fee from paypal if he does not want to receive the funds.

I use srmklive/paypal package for handling paypal payment method and right now my code makes immediate capture on order confirmation from user. Those things were so much easier to setup on Stripe...

**This is my current paypal portion of code in checkout controller:**

```
if ($request->input('payment_option') === 'paypal'){
            $provider = new PayPalClient();
            $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
            // $provider->setCurrency('EUR');
            $paypalToken = $provider->getAccessToken();

            $response = $provider->createOrder([
                "intent" => "CAPTURE",
                "application_context" => [
                    "return_url" => route('payment.success'),
                    "cancel_url" => route('payment.cancel'),
                ],
                "purchase_units" => [
                    [
                        'description' => "Globus Transfers - " . strtoupper($vehicle) . " taxi transfer reservation from $departureLocationName to $destinationLocationName.",
                        "amount" => [
                            "currency_code" => "EUR",
                            "value" => $price
                        ],
                        
                    ]
                ]
            ]);

            if(isset($response['id']) && $response['id'] != 'null') {
                // Store the order ID in the session
                session(['paypal_order_id' => $response['id']]);

                foreach($response['links'] as $link){
                    if($link['rel'] === 'approve'){
                        return redirect()->away($link['href']);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('payment.cancel');
            }
```

**And this is my success method in PaymentController:**

```
if($routeAndReservationData['payment_option'] === 'paypal'){
            $provider = new PayPalClient();
            $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
            $paypalToken = $provider->getAccessToken();
            $orderId = session('paypal_order_id');
            $response = $provider->showOrderDetails($request->token);
            // Capture the payment
            $captureResponse = $provider->capturePaymentOrder($orderId);


            if(isset($captureResponse['status']) && $captureResponse['status'] == 'COMPLETED'){
                // Update the reservation with the PayPal transaction ID
                $reservation->update(['paypal_order_id' => $orderId]);
                // Send confirmation email to the user
                Mail::to($routeAndReservationData['email'])->send(new UserReservationCreation($routeAndReservationData));
                Mail::to('example@gmail.com')->send(new CompanyReservationCreation($routeAndReservationData));
                session()->flush();
                return view('payment.success');
            } else {
                return view('payment.cancel');
            }
```

What methods i need to use to make the described functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the right method is:

```
$captureResponse = $provider->authorizePaymentOrder($orderId);
```

It does exactly what i asked for!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to setup paypal payment authorization in my laravel app so the seller has the option to review the offer and reject payment
>
> ...
>
> "intent" => "CAPTURE",

Use `"intent" => "AUTHORIZE"` for that behavior.

For more information see: [Authorize a payment and capture funds later](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/standard/customize/auth-capture/#link-overview). (The part about being a partner and using the purchase_units.payee object to specify a receiver does not apply to first-party integrations with the receiver's own API credentials.)

---

Edit with more details:

You also need to change what happens in your "success" method after approval. Instead of doing an orders /capture on the order, you need to call the /authorize endpoint.

Also your database should not be recording the PayPal Order ID. The Order ID is temporary and only used for the payer's approval; it is not the PayPal transaction ID, and does not serve any accounting purpose. Instead, save `purchase_units[0]->payments->authorizations[0].id`

Comment: I already tried "intent" => "AUTHORIZE" but it didn't work. The paypal portion of code in success method should be modified too. There should be probably some other method then "$captureResponse = $provider->capturePaymentOrder($orderId);" and the condition "if(isset($captureResponse['status']) && $captureResponse['status'] == 'COMPLETED'){.." should be probably like "if(isset($captureResponse['status']) && $captureResponse['status'] == 'PROCESSED')". I need more help with this since the documentation is very vague to me, thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need to change after-approval capture function to do an "/authorize" call instead of the "/capture" it is doing. Added some more detail above.

Comment: I found the solution, the right method is " $captureResponse = $provider->authorizePaymentOrder($orderId);". It does exactly what i asked for! I am just not sure what condition is better to use for response check "if(isset($response['status']) && $response['status'] == 'APPROVED'){.." or some other like =='AUTHORIZED' or =='PROCESSED'.

Comment: The status of the order and the status of the payment are two separate things. Order's status should be COMPLETED; payment's status should be PENDING (pending reason = it's an authorization, this is what authorizations are for)

Answer (score 0):

I already tried "intent" => "AUTHORIZE" but it didn't work. The paypal portion of code in success method should be modified too. There should be probably some other method then "$captureResponse = $provider->capturePaymentOrder($orderId);" and the condition "if(isset($captureResponse['status']) && $captureResponse['status'] == 'COMPLETED'){.." should be probably like "if(isset($captureResponse['status']) && $captureResponse['status'] == 'PROCESSED')". I need more help with this since the documentation is very vague to me, thank you!

Comment: These kind of posts should be managed as comments on the original posts, and not as answers on the original post.